# Processing-java sketch( server ) not responding in the way I want it to

Tags: input, client, server, processing

I have created a processing-java sketch. This sketch is the server. All I want this program to do is that the client and server can connect and write messages(sentences) between each other. Case 1 was successful, but case 2 was not. I have explained the process for each case and what went wrong/successful.

Case 1) On the same computer(Mac), I started the server program and on Terminal("Command Prompt" on Mac), I typed `telnet local host 5204` and the client(Mac) connected with the server(Mac). I was able to type sentences (or Strings) between the server and client and it was successful. So whatever sentence I type in the server, it was visible to the client and vice versa. **Note: The server and client were both in the same computer.**

Case 2) On the Mac, I started the server program. On another computer(Windows 7)
I connected to the server via Command Prompt. The connection was successful. In this case, the Strings could be sent from the server to the client and the Strings were visible to the client. **But when I tried to send Strings to the server from the client, the server could only receive the information character by character, not as an entire sentence/String.** I tried changing the port number, the client device, the frameRate, but I still had no success.

This is my problem. Please comment if my question could be clearer or if I need to give more details. Thank you for answering.

Below is my Server code:

```
import processing.net.*;

Server myServer;
//Strings from server and client
String typing = "";
String c = "";

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  //creating server on port 5204
  myServer = new Server(this, 5204); 
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  //displaying server's text and client's text
  fill(0);
  text(typing, 100, 100);
  text("Client: " + c, 100, 150);
  Client client = myServer.available();

  if(client != null) {
      //reading input from client
      c = client.readString();
      c.trim();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  //Server can type sentences to client
  if(key == '\n') {
    myServer.write(typing + '\n');
    typing = "";
  }else{
    typing = typing + key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/) for Windows?

With it you can try: `echo Text to send & echo. | ncat localhost 5204`

[Source](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/464761-send-a-text-to-telnet-port-using-single-line-command?page=1#entry-3137831)